# Laravel nested 'with ' function complex query problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel I want to fetch data from table 1 that has 'one to many' relations with table 2, which again has 'one to many' relation with Table 3.

For e.g, I have a USER table, POSTS table and COMMENTS table. 
One user to have many posts and each of those posts to have many comments.

I only want to run a query that will return each of the users, with their post (single) THAT has the latest comment (single) (among all the comments in all the post of that user).

[image: Image illustration of the data]

I have tried Laravel nested 'with' function but I am having trouble with constructing the query.

Comment: Please look at the image for better understanding

Comment: Please crop the image next time

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
 $user = USERS::with(['posts' =>function($query) { $query->with(['comments'])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first(); } ])->where('user_id',$id)->get();
```

Hope it works.

Let me know if you get any error(s)

Comment: No man, using first() method to fetch a single comment returns empty post as a result. I tried this before.

P.S I am trying to get result for a collection of users, not for a single user.

Comment: You can get that by removing where condition at the end, I think.

I hope you already have methods in model for relationship like hasMany

Answer (score 0):

use join method like below :

```
$comments = User::join('posts', 
 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->join('comments', 'comments.post_id', '=', 
 'posts.id')->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'desc')->first();
```